# How to check if a container is running and trigger another container as a result?

Tags: docker

I have container 1 that takes a bit of time to spin up and get ready.

And I have container 2 that needs to run once container 1 is ready.

How can container 2 make sure container 1 is ready before it runs?

This needs to happen using a single Cron job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
PATH=:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 0 * * * docker ...¹; until docker ps | grep '<SOME SPECIFIC STRING>; do sleep 1; done; docker run ...²
```

Replace `docker ...¹` and `docker ...²` by the real `docker` commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker swarm or docker-compose.

`docker-stack.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  slow-to-start-service:
    image: xxx

  needy-service:
    image: yyy
    depends_on:           # <-- this will not start until slow-to-start-service us up
      - slow-to-start-service
```

`crontab -e`

```
0 * * * * docker stack deploy -c /path/to/docker-stack.yml --prune my-stack
```